# Search Product EAN/GTIN by Product Title

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a Free API that can take product title and return product data including GTIN, EAN etc. I googled a lot but could not find an API.
Has anybody used a C# API?

Free API is preferred but a limited version will also work if free is not available.

**Possible workaround:** I have written a script using Selenium/C# and it opens eBay in a browser and search for the a product based on the title and then opens every search result in another browser and read the HTML and parse the GTIN from there.
If GTIN is not found in first search result, then it opens the next search result and keep searching for next 10 results.
Ig GTIN is found, it is written in a CSV file or a database for further usage.

Comment: are you searching for this kind api...? https://www.programmableweb.com/api/open-eangtin-database-rest-api

Comment: yes, similar to that but this api requires an ean which i can't provide. I just have a title.

Answer (score -1):

Search for EAN, UPC, ISBN or product names: https://www.ean-search.org/

It has also REST based API to search full database with over 280 million barcodes, make automated queries and integrate into your own applications.

EAN API Features:

1. query products by EAN/UPC code (or prefix eg. 0885909*)
2. search by product name
3. product category data for many products
4. responses in XML or JSON
5. API can be queried directly from within Excel 2013 or later
6. code samples provided for Java, PHP, Python, Go and C#
7. generate EAN barcode images (PNG to display or print)

Comment: I am looking for a free api.

Comment: @Ali do you find any??

Comment: no, i could find.